# What are these markings under the passenger door?

Tags: aircraft-marking

Is there anybody who can explain what the markings just below the passenger door edge do?

[image: British Airways plane at gate]

Comment: I do not think the catering truck will be able to approach the front left passenger door. Am i wrong?

Comment: I have only ever seen catering trucks on the starboard side of the aircraft where foodstuffs can be unloaded directly into galley without affecting passengers planing and deplaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They appear to be alignment marks for the passenger loading bridge (PLB) and air stairs. Some airlines choose mark their aircraft and bridges, in order to prevent damage to the aircraft door due to misalignment of the bridge or air stairs.

On the PLB, there will be a corresponding mark on the floor, at the edge.

The two lower marks would be used for air stair alignment (i.e., when a PLB is not available).

Note the marks at the edge of the bridge in this photo (the position of the alignment marks are not standardized and are carrier specific):

[image: Air stairs abutting aircraft]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i can not view the linked photo of the marked bridge adjacent to the aircraft. Can you give me an open link for it.

Comment: The photo is hosted on StackExchange's Imgur instance, which is publicly available. If you can't see it, it is possible that Imgur is being blocked (perhaps by your company or ISP).

Comment: Sometimes imgur is "over capacity" and that shows broken links in SE posts. Give it some time.